# fortran90 reading array with real numbers

Tags: fortran90

I have a list of real data in a file. The real data looks like this..

```
 25.935
 25.550
 24.274
 29.936
 23.122
 27.360
 28.154
 24.320
 28.613
 27.601
 29.948
 29.367
```

I write fortran90 code to read this data into an array as below:

```
PROGRAM autocorr
implicit none

INTEGER, PARAMETER :: TRUN=4000,TCOR=1800

 real,dimension(TRUN) :: angle

real :: temp, temp2, average1, average2
integer :: i, j, p, q, k, count1, t, count2

REAL, DIMENSION(0:TCOR) :: ACF

 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

open(100, file="fort.64",status="old")
do k = 1,TRUN
    read(100,*) angle(k)
end do
```

Then, when I print again to see the values, I get

25.934999
   25.549999
   24.274000
   29.936001
   23.122000
   27.360001
   28.153999
   24.320000
   28.613001
   27.601000
   29.948000
   29.367001
   32.122002
   33.818001
   21.837000
   29.283001
   26.489000
   24.010000
   27.698000
   30.799999
   36.157001
   29.034000
   34.700001
   26.058001
   29.114000
   24.177000
   25.209000
   25.820999
   26.620001
   29.761000

May I know why the values are now 6 decimal points?
How to avoid this effect so that it doesn't affect the calculation results?

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: What is your declaration of `angle`? There is an implicit conversion to `REAL` or `DOUBLE PRECISION` going on here.

Comment: I declared as REAL. Not DOUBLE PRECISION. I have edited the code for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the statement you use to write the values out again.  I suspect, therefore, that you've used Fortran's *list-directed* output, something like this

```
write(output_unit,*) angle(k)
```

If you have done this you have surrendered the control of how many digits the program displays to the compiler.  That's what the use of `*` in place of an explicit format means, the standard says that the compiler can use any reasonable representation of the number.

What you are seeing, therefore, is your numbers displayed with 8 sf which is about what single-precision floating-point numbers provide.  If you wanted to display the numbers with only 3 digits after the decimal point you could write

```
write(output_unit,'(f8.3)') angle(k)
```

or some variation thereof.

You've declared `angle` to be of type `real`; unless you've overwritten the default with a compiler flag, this means that you are using single-precision IEEE754 floating-point numbers (on anything other than an exotic computer).  Bear in mind too that most real (in the mathematical sense) numbers do not have an exact representation in floating-point and that the single-precision decimal approximation to the exact number `25.935` is likely to be `25.934999`; the other numbers you print seem to be the floating-point approximations to the numbers your program reads.

If you really want to compute your results with a lower precision, then you are going to have to employ some clever programming techniques.